# Angular router outlet cutting draggable UI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm trying to create a drag and drop folder like behavior for an angular/ionic project. In the background it works perfectly fine but visually the drag element gets cut off when it is not fully visible in the viewport. Below a visual representation of what i'm trying to say.

| Image | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | UI Element cut off while being dragged when partially out of viewport |
| [image] | UI Element shown fully when being dragged when fully in viewport |

Here is a project i created where the issue can be reproduced.
https://github.com/Deitsch/ionic-draggable-cutoff

I have found out that this only happens if both circumstances apply:

- the draggable element being outside of the viewport
- the element is a component loaded in an `router-outlet`

The drag works fine in a simple html file like the example code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    .box {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .spacer {
        height: 700px;
        width: 20px;
    }
</style>
<html>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="box" draggable="true"></div>
</html>
```

What can i do to get the whole HTML element when dragging in an `router-outlet`?

Comment: It's because some parent container has overflow set to hidden/scroll/auto. If in your plain html example you will wrap your box in container with overflow:hidden and make your box visible only partially, the effect will be the same.
To overcome this, you would need to play a bit with moving your dragged element outside of clipping container, or cloning it. Or use some 3rd party lib for drag&drop, like dragula.

Comment: Do you know a library for drag and drop folder like behavior? Dragula and most others work for lists, but not for my desired behavior

Comment: I've tried to remove the overflow, if you can do in in the example and give me a PR i'll award you the 200 pts